# Cambiar el true por false en tabla sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un `form` donde solamente tengo una tabla con un `input` de tipo `checkbox` con todos los "Agentes" que tengo en una tabla de sql lo que serían en total unos 27 registros.

Cuando desmarco uno y envió los datos al controlador, me llegan 26 quitando al que desmarque.  Pero cuando quiero guardar esa info en la tabla no se me desmarca y lo sigo teniendo como true en vez de false.

```
public ActionResult ActualizarAgentes(List<int> Activo)
        {

            //var agentes = db.Agentes.Where(x => Activo.Contains(x.AgenteId)).ToList();
            var agentes = db.Agentes.FirstOrDefault(x => Activo.Contains(x.AgenteId));

            string checkBoxSi = Request.Form["Activo"];

            string[] check = checkBoxSi.Split(',');

            int[] arr = new int[check.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < check.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = int.Parse(check[i]);
            }

            List<int[]> lista = new List<int[]>
            {
                arr
            };


            if (arr[0] > 0)
            {
                foreach (var agente in lista[0])
                {
                    agentes.Activo = true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                agentes.Activo = false;
            }
            //else if(checkBoxNo != "true")
            //{
            //    foreach (var agente in agentes)
            //    {
            //        agente.Activo = false;
            //    }
            //}

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Lo que recibo en el parámetro de la función es una lista con todo los Id de los Agentes que tengo seleccionados (que están checked),en string `checkBoxSi` también obtiene todos los Id que estén `checked` pero en formato de string  y luego los convierto en un arreglo de enteros. Pero en problema en sí esta en el `foreach` que no me selecciona todos los Agentes de la lista si no que solo me selecciona el que se de seleccione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque solo estás actualizando los activos, los inactivos los estas dejando igual, prueba algo como esto

```
public ActionResult ActualizarAgentes(List<int> Activo)
{
    foreach (var item in db.Agentes)
    {
        item.Activo = Activo.Contains(item.AgenteId);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho